# Income tax - investment proof submission when switching jobs

Tags: income-tax, india

I am switching jobs in the last week of November.

In my current organization, the investment proof submission for income tax calculation usually happens in January first week. So I will definitely not be able to do it in my current organization since I m moving out in November.

Question is: Will the company I'm joining in November end accept the income tax investment proofs?

Posting here to check if any one has experienced this before and how it worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will the company I'm joining in November end accept the income tax investment proofs?

This would depend on the Organization and the type of investment in question.

Section 80C, yes you can submit this to new Organization and they are bound to accept it.

House Rent, Medical, LTA etc may not be accepted by the new Organization for the full period. They normally would consider this for partial period.

> In my current organization, the investment proof submission for income tax calculation usually happens in January first week. So I will definitely not be able to do it in my current organization

There is no reason why your current Organization cannot do this. Please check and confirm that they will not be able to accept investment proofs.

Comment: thanks, question was mainly related to investments considered for excemption under 80c